# Regular Expression to match a pattern that contain some string except some string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I have string  like following:

```
var string = "'abc'+@VAL([Q].[F1 w1 w1 w1])+ 'hellllllllllo'+@VAL([Q].[F2 w]) +'anything'+@VAL([Q].[F3 w])+anything";
```

i want to match the following pattern

```
@VAL([Q].[F1 w1 w1 w1])
@VAL([Q].[F2 w]) 
@VAL([Q].[F3 w])
```

actually i  want to match a string pattern  start with **@VAL(** and end with  **)** 
I have tried with the following code:

```
   var patt1 = /@VAL\((.*)\)/g;

   var myPattern = string.match(patt1);
```

and get the following result

```
@VAL([Q].[F1 w1 w1 w1])+ 'hellllllllllo'+@VAL([Q].[F2 w]) +'anything'+@VAL([Q].[F3 w])
```

i could not sort it out need help!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all the matches:

```
result = subject.match(/@VAL\([^)]*\)/g);
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xV6hH1).

- `@VAL\(` matches `@VAL(`
- `[^)]` matches one character that is not a `)`...
- and the `*` quantifier repeats that zero or more times
- `*\)` matches the closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is too greedy, Use this **negation based** regex:

```
var patt1 = /@VAL\(([^)]*)\)/g;
```

OR just make it lazy:

```
var patt1 = /@VAL\((.*?)\)/g;


var m = string.match(patt1);
//=> ["@VAL([Q].[F1 w1 w1 w1])", "@VAL([Q].[F2 w])", "@VAL([Q].[F3 w])"]
```